# Exact meaning of == in C

Tags: c, operators

I am a bit confused about the exact meaning of operator `==` in C.

Does it compare mathematical values variables represent (depending on their types) or the bit patterns behind the variables? Specifically:

```
int x = 0x80000000;
unsigned y = x;
x==y // true
```

So despite the fact that x is a large negative value and y is a large positive they are equal (I guess because they have the same bit pattern).

```
int64_t x = 0x8000000000000000;
int y = x;
x==y // false
```

Here it does not matter that the first (least significant) 32 bits in x and y are the same. So it looks like in this case C looks at the values represented by the variables.

What are the official rules and is there an authoritative reference for this (have not found anything useful on this in K&R)?

I have used `gcc` compiler for the above examples.

Comment: You think `x` and `y` in the second example will have the same bit pattern? How large the `int` in your environment is?

Comment: `Here it does not matter that the first (least significant) 32 bits in x and y are the same` -- That's right, because the 32 most significant bits are *not* the same.

Comment: I think you're just suffering from a lack of knowledge about how bits work in computer systems.  Regardless of your understanding, the second example is a *lossy conversion;*  you're going to unavoidably throw away some bits when you assign y to x, because y is a 32 bit number and x is a 64 bit number, and there's simply no way to store all 64 bits.  Ergo, the two numbers are simply not going to be equal.

Comment: Demo here:  https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/UrbanUprightDrivers#main.c

Comment: " is there an authoritative reference" - Yes, the ISO Standard for the C programming Language, ISO/IEC 9899:2017

Comment: @MSalters: Which, at the OP's current level of understanding, will take probably a year to digest.

Comment: @RobertHarvey then now would be a good time to start :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It doesn't get a whole lot faster if you have 20 years of experience. Sure, the simple bits are easier, but you no longer gloss over the tricky parts.

Comment: K&R is not the best book to look for these because the **original** predated the standard where this stuff was settled, and the **2nd edition was published when the first standard was being finalized**.

And `int64_t` became a thing ~10 years *after* the 2nd edition...

Comment: In the second example, the value in `y` is 0 because the value in `x` is too big to fit into `y`.  Since `x` is not zero, it is not surprising that when `y` (`0`) is converted to a 64-bit integer, it is still zero and that is different from what is in `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at the initialization of `x`.  Assuming a 32-bit `int`, the constant `0x80000000` has type `unsigned int` with value 2<sup>31</sup>.  So this constant must  be converted to type `int`.  Section 6.3.1.3p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) dictates how this happens:

> Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So an implementation-defined conversion happens.  On a two's complement system, this is typically implemented by assigning the low 32 bits of the value in question's representation directly to the object to be assigned to.  This results in `x` having the value -2<sup>31</sup>.

Now `x` is assigned to `y`.  This means the value is converted from `int` to `unsigned int`, and the value in question is negative.  So the conversion is dictated by section 6.3.1.3p2:

> Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than  the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type until the value is in the range of the new type

The maximum value for `unsigned int` (assuming 32 bit) is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, so one more than this is 2<sup>32</sup>.  Adding 2<sup>32</sup> to -2<sup>31</sup> gives us 2<sup>31</sup> which is what is stored in `y`.

Now to the comparison.

When two different arithmetic types are compared via the `==` operator, they undergo the **usual arithmetic conversions**.

Section 6.3.1.8p1 of the C standard states the following regarding how two integer types are converted:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
> needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
> unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser
> integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
> with greater rank.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has
> rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other
> operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is
> converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
> type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
> represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
> integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is
> converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
> integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
> integer type.

The paragraph in bold is the one that applies here since we're comparing an `int` with an `unsigned int`.  So the value of `x` is converted to the type `unsigned int`.

Going back to the conversion rules of section 6.3.1.3p2, the maximum value for `unsigned int` (assuming 32 bit) is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, so one more than this is 2<sup>32</sup>.  Adding 2<sup>32</sup> to the value of `x`, i.e. -2<sup>31</sup>, gives us 2<sup>31</sup>.  This is the same as the value of `y`, so the comparison is true.

In the second example where `x` has type `int64_t` and `y` has type `int`, the implementation-defined conversion from `int64_t`  to `int` when `x` is assigned to `y` likely results in `y` being 0 since the lower 32 bits of `x` are all 0.

Answer (score 7):

You have jumped to a conclusion in asking about whether the comparison is based on values or bit patterns, because there is an important step first. Before comparison, the operands of `==` are converted to a common type.

As an example, when you compare a 32-bit two’s complement `int x` with the bit pattern 1000…0000<sub>2</sub> (representing −2,147,483,648) and an `unsigned int y` with the same bit pattern (representing +2,147,483,648) with `x == y`, the `x` is first converted to `unsigned int`, which produces +2,147,483,648. Then +2,147,483,648 is compared to +2,147,483,648, so `==` reports they are equal.

C 2018 6.5.9 (“Equality operators”) 4 says:

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed…

The *usual arithmetic conversions* are specified in 6.3.1.8. Paragraph 1 starts:

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted… to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type.

The rules involve some technical details, but, in large part, when you compare two integer types, first each will be promoted to at least `int`, and then the narrower type will be converted to the wider type. If they are the same width but one is unsigned, the signed type will be converted to the unsigned type. This may change the value.

Once the actual values to be compared are determined, the result of `==` is defined in terms of the values, not the bit pattern.

(The most common situation where these differ is with floating-point +0 and −0, which represent the same real number and compare equal but have different representations. In most modern environments, all bit patterns in an integer type represent different values, and all bit patterns in a binary floating-point type represent either different values or NaNs except for +0 and −0. There are some less commonly used floating-point types that have multiple representations for some values, analogous to the way 3.5•10<sup>7</sup> and 35•10<sup>6</sup> represent the same number.)

Anytime you compare a negative value in a signed integer type to an unsigned type that is the same width or wider (after the promotions), the value of the signed type will be changed before the comparison. So you have a risk of getting a “mathematically wrong” result.

Answer (score 2):

The exact meaning per the language definition:

> **6.2.6 Representations of types**
> **6.2.6.1 General**
> 4    Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* × **`CHAR_BIT`**
> bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into
> an object of type **`unsigned char [n]`** (e.g., by **`memcpy`**); the resulting set of bytes is
> called the *object representation* of the value. Values stored in bit-fields consist of *m* bits,
> where *m* is the size specified for the bit-field. The object representation is the set of *m*
> bits the bit-field comprises in the addressable storage unit holding it. ***Two values (other
> than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal, but values that compare
> equal may have different object representations.***
> ...
>
> **6.5.9 Equality operators**
> ...
> 4    ***If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
> performed.*** Values of complex types are equal if and only if both their real parts are equal
> and also their imaginary parts are equal. Any two values of arithmetic types from
> different type domains are equal if and only if the results of their conversions to the
> (complex) result type determined by the usual arithmetic conversions are equal.
> 5    Otherwise, at least one operand is a pointer. If one operand is a pointer and the other is a
> null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer. If
> one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or
> unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.
> 6    Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the
> same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function,
> both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer
> to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different
> array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address
> space.<sup>109)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>109) Two objects may be adjacent in memory because they are adjacent elements of a larger array or
> adjacent members of a structure with no padding between them, or because the implementation chose
> to place them so, even though they are unrelated. If prior invalid pointer operations (such as accesses
> outside array bounds) produced undefined behavior, subsequent comparisons also produce undefined
> behavior.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

*Semantically speaking*, the `==` operator is comparing values, not bits - `1.0 == 1` will evaluate to `true` even though both operands have completely different bitwise representations.

However, as part of the comparison, the integer `1` will first be converted to the floating-point `1.0` so that a bitwise comparison *can* be made.

Comment: `However, as part of the comparison, the integer 1 will first be converted to the floating-point 1.0 so that a bitwise comparison can be made.` -- Wait, what?  Why?  Nothing prevents a bitwise comparison between two integers, and floating point has [all kinds of woes](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) in this area.

Comment: @RobertHarvey — if you compare `1.0 == 1`, then the LHS is a `double` and the RHS will be converted to a `double` and the comparison will be performed between the two `double` values.  That's what the standard specifies; it is what C has always done.  With constant expressions, the conversion and computation is probably done at compile time.  If one of the values was a variable reference or an expression involving variables, then the conversion is done at compile time.  That there might be problems with accuracy is irrelevant; the standard says that is what must happen.